# OOP Design - In Python, is this a quality OO Design or an epic fail?

Tags: python, django, oop

In a system that accepts orders which have payments which have gateway transactions should the objects be like this:

```
class Order(object):
        ... Inside init ...
        self.total_in_dollars = <Dollar Amount>
        self.is_paid = <Boolean Value>

class Payment(object):
        ... Inside init ...
        self.order = order_instance
        self.amount = order.total_in_dollars

class GatewayTransaction(object):
        ... Inside init ...
        self.payment = payment_instance
        self.amount = <Dollar Amount>
```

It seems this would be the way to do it (obviously this is not real code with integer dollar amounts, etc but you get the picture). I did it this way because an **order can exist without payment** and a **payment can exist before an actual PayPal transaction occurs**. Does this lack in your opinion? Am I backwards in my thinking?

**OR**, Should it be more like this:

```
class GatewayTransaction(object):
    payment = payment_instance
    amount = <Dollar Amount>

class Payment(object):
    amount = <Dollar Amount>
    gateway_transaction = gateway_transaction_instance

class Order(object):
    amount_in_dollars = <Dollar Amount>
    payment = payment_instance
```

Comment: You seem to have several Python related questions and have some hard time about it :-) Keep it up, your questions are good and they will be answered.

Comment: @e-satis I really am not a noob, although it appears I am. I've spent years studying cognitive science and this idea of asking the obvious to see what comes of it is a great way to grow your skills. For instance, in this question Alex answered with his weakref example, and I've never used weakref. I've learned something great now for memory efficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be assigning what should obviously be **instance** variables as **class** variables, which is clearly a very wrong tack to take.  IOW, the variables should be `self.total_in_dollars` (for instance of `Order`) and so forth, assigned in `__init__`, **not** class-variables, assigned in the `class` statement!

Simply creating an instance of `Order` without a corresponding one of `Payment` is fine (and should obviously set `is_paid` to `False`), based just on the total (and presumably some numeric ID  so customers &c can in the future refer to a specific order).

Don't duplicate information needlessly!  Since a `Payment` instance will always have a reference to an `Order` instance, it should **not** copy `self.order.total_in_dollars` over to `self.amount` -- better to have that information in **one** place (you can make a readonly `property` if you want to access it nicely); and even more so for the transaction instances.

If an Order instance carried further metadata that influences how the corresponding Payment instance is created and behaves, that's OK, but strongly suggests making the creation of the Payment instance the job of a factory-method of class Object (which can then also keep track of already-generated instances and ensure there will never be more than one Payment instance for a single given Order instance).

**Edit**: now that the OP has somewhat edited the A, I can confirm the opinion that the dependencies in the first version are roughly correct (except, again, the amount should not get copied all over the place) and those in the second versions are, prima facie, not correct (the presence of a mutual/circular dependency for example is always a design smell unless clearly and explicitly justified by special application needs -- even when the need to navigate back and forth exists, one of the two links should be a weak reference, at least).

**Edit**: as the OP explicitly asks for more detail on the factory method I suggested, what I had in mind was something like this:

```
import weakref

class Payment(object):
  def __init__(self, order):
    self.order = weakref.proxy(order, self.ordergone)
  def ordergone(self, *_):
    self.order = None
  @property
  def amount(self):
    if self.order is None: return None
    else: return self.order.total_in_dollars

class Order(object):
  def __init__(self, amount):
    self.total_in_dollars = amount
    self.is_paid = False
    self._payment = None
  @property
  def payment(self):
    if self._payment is None:
      self._payment = Payment(self)
    return self._payment
```

Comment: Oops, I just edited my typo (for the first example anyways). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. Can you give me an example of how you might implement the last paragraph. I'm interested (ie, I don't know much about factory pattern but have wanted to learn).

Comment: Thanks Alex for the example. I don't fully understand it because I don't understand what weakref does exactly (I just barely learned about weakref a few hours ago and plan to research it more now). I'm assuming that it just gives you a reference to an object without increasing the reference count of that object.

Comment: Also, what does the *_ do in the ordergone() method?

Comment: Having `*whatever` as the last parameter in a `def` mean: accept any further positional arguments. For the `whatever` I use `_` because I intend to ignore those arguments and it's a common convention to name `_` a variable that you intend to ignore. And yes, "weak references" (both refs and proxies, just minor differences) serve to access an object as long as it's alive but without _keeping_ it alive -- on building them you can also pass a callback that gets called right after the object disappears (if the object disappears before the ref or proxy does).

Comment: Oh, thanks. The _ through me off, so I didn't even think about *args.

Answer (score 2):

Give the objects constructors that take the appropriate other object that you want it to refer to, then make the fields into properties that verify the type you assign to them.

Comment: What about the aspect of missing parts (ie, I create an Order with no Payment), and also the part where I don't know how to create the Payment (ie, the Order may have a payment_choice attribute and I create a Payment that references Order.payment_choice to determine how to process it).

Comment: Clearly there's no need to require a value that isn't required; if there's nothing wrong with having an attribute be None then allow that in the property and have that as the default argument in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this differently - by writing the some code for dealing with Orders, Payments etc. This would clarify my design needs, e.g. it would turn out that Payment.amount could be greater that Order.total_in_dollars, because of some processing fees. But then, it could turn out that maybe those processing fees should be stored separately, or even they could/should have their own model.
And yes, this is **TDD**.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. In other words, the style that works best is determined based on needs along the way, vs an end-all-be-all approach to the perfect OO design.